# Use DBPedia to load all People along with some data

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am using DBpedia for the first time. I would like to download all the people in the dataset of people along with properties for commonName, nationality, birthDate, and knownFor (I will eventually stick it into an excel spread sheet using some sort of scripting language I think).

This was my first attempt at a query to do this job, however it does not work. I tried piecing it together from other bits of code I've seen on the internet. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 

SELECT ?person ?commonName ?nationality ?knownFor ? birthDate
WHERE {
    ?person a type:Person .
    ?person prop:commonName ?commonNameFilter(lang(?commonName) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:nationality ?nationality(lang(?nationality) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:knownFor ?knownFor(lang(?knownFor) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:birthDate ?birthDate .
}
```

**EDIT: NEW VERSION OF CODE: RETURNS COMMONNAME (WITH NON-ENGLISH DUPLICATES). STILL MISSING OTHER PROPERTIES.**

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person ;  
              dbpedia-owl:commonName ?commonName . FILTER(lang(?commonName) = 'en')
}
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Do you get an error?  A set of results that you're not expecting?  What results _are_ you getting?

Comment: Well, now with your help with the code. I can get commonName, although there are some duplicates and some that are not actually in English even though I filtered for them. Just missing the other fields I guess

Comment: It's OK to edit your question with updates, but please don't remove the old code.  It removes the context and content that the original answers were referring to.  If you're going to post new code, please do it _add_ the new content, not _replace_ the old content.  It would be great if you can rollback that edit, and make the edit as an addition, rather than a replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your query has a bunch of syntax issues:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
            ^ you probably want to use the dbpedia-owl properties which are 
            # in <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?person ?commonName ?nationality ?knownFor ? birthDate
                                                   ^ space between ? and varname
WHERE {
    ?person a type:Person .
    ?person prop:commonName ?commonNameFilter(lang(?commonName) = 'en') .
                                       ^ This needs to be "?commonName . FILTER(..."
                                       # and the same thing applies to your other 
                                       # filters
    ?person prop:nationality ?nationality(lang(?nationality) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:knownFor ?knownFor(lang(?knownFor) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:birthDate ?birthDate .
}
```

It's easier to build some of these queries incrementally, because then you can find out what properties some of the resources *actually* have, and then you can extend your query some more.  The public endpoint has a number of [predefined namespaces](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), and using those will make it easier for others to read your query.  So, you can start by asking for people:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person .
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?person%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Person%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Seeing that that's working, you can look at some of the returned instances and see that they have `dbpedia-owl:commonName` properties, and then extend the query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person ;  
              dbpedia-owl:commonName ?commonName .
}
LIMIT 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?person%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Person%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:commonName%20?commonName%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

It's easy enough to extend this with the `dbpedia-owl:birthDate` property. I don't see a `nationality` predicate on the instances that I've looked at, so I'm not sure what you were basing the nationality query on.  While I saw some use of the `knownFor` property, I didn't see it on many instances, so if you make it a required property, you're going to exclude lots of people.  This sort of incremental approach will probably help you out in the long run, though.

#### Finding Properties

While the browseable ontology provides a nice way to find *classes*, I'm not sure whether there's such a nice way of finding *properties*.  However, you can do something in a brute force manner.  E.g., to find all the properties that have actually been used for `Person`s, you can run a query like the following.  (Note: this query takes a while to execute, so if you use it, you should probably download the results.)

```
select distinct ?p where {
  [] a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
     ?p [] .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?p%20where%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Person%20;%20?p%20%5B%5D%20.%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I'll note that `dbpedia-owl:nationality` *does* appear in that list.

To get all the properties for everything, you can [download the ontology](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38#h224-1), and run a query like:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select * where { 
  { ?p a owl:ObjectProperty }
  UNION 
  { ?p a owl:DatatypeProperty }
}
```

I ran this locally using Jena's ARQ:

```
$ arq --query properties.sparql --data dbpedia_3.8.owl
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| p                                                                        |
============================================================================
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/regionServed>                               |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/coachedTeam>                                |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/legalForm>                                  |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/goldenCalfAward>                            |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/composer>                                   |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/owningOrganisation>                         |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/branchFrom>                                 |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/iso6393Code>                                |
...
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/classification>                             |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/bgafdId>                                    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/currencyCode>                               |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/onChromosome>                               |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/course>                                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/frequentlyUpdated>                          |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/distance>                                   |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/volume>                                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/description>                                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That won't provide the `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range`, but you could also ask for these, or for just those properties with `rdfs:range dbpedia-owl:Person` (but note that this won't get all the properties that could be used `Person`, since the range could be more or less specific):

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?p ?range where { 
  { ?p a owl:ObjectProperty }
  UNION 
  { ?p a owl:DatatypeProperty }

  ?p rdfs:domain dbpedia-owl:Person ; rdfs:range ?range .
}


$ arq --query properties.sparql --data dbpedia_3.8.owl | head
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| p                                           | range                                                  |
========================================================================================================
| dbpedia-owl:restingPlacePosition            | <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#SpatialThing> |
| dbpedia-owl:opponent                        | dbpedia-owl:Person                                     |
| dbpedia-owl:employer                        | dbpedia-owl:Organisation                               |
| dbpedia-owl:hometown                        | dbpedia-owl:Settlement                                 |
| dbpedia-owl:militaryBranch                  | dbpedia-owl:MilitaryUnit                               |
| dbpedia-owl:school                          | dbpedia-owl:EducationalInstitution                     |
| dbpedia-owl:ethnicity                       | dbpedia-owl:EthnicGroup                                |
...
| dbpedia-owl:sex                             | xsd:string                                             |
| dbpedia-owl:hipSize                         | xsd:double                                             |
| dbpedia-owl:individualisedPnd               | xsd:nonNegativeInteger                                 |
| dbpedia-owl:weddingParentsDate              | xsd:date                                               |
| dbpedia-owl:birthName                       | xsd:string                                             |
| dbpedia-owl:networth                        | xsd:double                                             |
| dbpedia-owl:birthYear                       | xsd:gYear                                              |
| dbpedia-owl:bustSize                        | xsd:double                                             |
| dbpedia-owl:description                     | xsd:string                                             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @AlexChumbley You can browse the instance data, or query DBpedia, or download the ontology and have a look at it.  I've updated the answer to show how.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very good at SPARQL yet, but i do see some syntax issues here. I rewrote the query to look like this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?person, ?commonName, ?nationality, ?knownFor, ?birthDate
WHERE {
    ?person a type:Person .
    ?person prop:commonName ?commonName .
    FILTER (lang(?commonName) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:nationality ?nationality .
    FILTER (lang(?nationality) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:knownFor ?knownFor .
    FILTER (lang(?knownFor) = 'en') .
    ?person prop:birthDate ?birthDate .
}
```

and now its at least running the query without an error. but i'm not seeing results. not sure why

Comment: Thanks! That's one big step forward, at least